# How to get value of changeset field

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am trying to get the value of `:amount` field. And based on that to calculate the offer. So basically I can't get the value of amount.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
schema "loans" do
  field :amount, :integer
  field :email, :string
  field :isHigher, :boolean, default: false
  field :names, :string
  field :offer, :integer, default: 0
  field :phoneNumber, :string

  timestamps()
end

@doc false
def changeset(loan, attrs) do
  loan
  |> cast(attrs, [:amount, :names, :phoneNumber, :email, :offer, :isHigher])
  |> validate_format(:names, ~r/^[A-Z][a-z]+ ([A-Z][a-z]+\s*)*$/)
  |> validate_format(:phoneNumber, ~r/^[0-9-: ]+$/)
  |> validate_format(:email, ~r/^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/)
  |> custom(:amount)
end 

defp custom(%{params: params} = changeset, field) when is_map(params) do 
  value = Map.get(params, param)
  if is_prime(value) do
    put_change(changeset, :offer, 12)
  end  

  changeset
end 

defp custom(changeset) do
  changeset
end

def is_prime(x), do: (2..x |> Enum.filter(fn a -> rem(x, a) == 0 end) |> length()) == 1
```

Answer (score 1):

[elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) is *an immutable language*.

That said, the below is *noop*. *Nothing* can be mutated (changed in-place.)

```
if is_prime(value) do
  put_change(changeset, :offer, 12)
end
```

This code returns and immediately throws away the result of a call to `put_change/3`.

To conditionally change the value, one should return the result:

```
value = Map.get(params, param)
if is_prime(value),
  do: put_change(changeset, :offer, 12),
  else: changeset
```

---

*Sidenote:* you never use `field` passed to `custom/2`, which makes me think you wanted somewhat like:

```
defp custom(%{params: %{} = params} = changeset, field) do 
  value = Map.get(params, to_string(field))
  if is_prime(value),
    do: put_change(changeset, :offer, 12),
    else: changeset
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Probably i didn't make myself clear enough, sorry i'm new to this. I want to get the value of :amount field. It's should be very simple but i can't get it to work. That's my main problem, aside from not understanding the language enough.

Comment: I am not sure I follow. To get to `amount` field in your changeset after cast, you might do `changeset.params["amount"]` (note it must be a string,) or `changeset.changes[:amount]` to get it if and only it has changed. The code I posted under _Sidenote_ should work out of the box. If not, please provide an MCVE and post what error you get.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [get_change](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#get_change/3) or [get_field](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#get_field/3) to get a field from a changeset. The first only looks in the changes, the latter looks in changes first and falls back on the data.

So what you can do is something like:

```
defp custom(changeset, field) do
  value = get_change(field)
  if is_prime(value) do
    put_change(changeset, :offer, 12)
  else
    changeset
  end
end
```

Comment: ROFL. How is it better than [`changeset.{changes,params}[field]`](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/blob/v3.1.7/lib/ecto/changeset.ex#L1038)?

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin I think it's more idiomatic to use `get_change`.